# how to track a gps module position with another gps?

Tags: gps

Can I track a GPS module location with an another GPS? Tracking is done by the victims approval and tracking GPS module Id is available. Can I track?

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest reading infos in the help center, before you ask a question. Your question is unfortunately off-topic.

Comment: No, you can't, as long a s you don't have access to the embedding device that contains the GPS module, via mobile data connection.